# Is there way to reset password if you can only login via ssh keys?

Tags: openssh, passwd

I don't know why but somehow my password no longer works. For example, I cannot do "su myself". I can still login via ssh keys. In such case, is there way to reset password?

Comment: You say you can login using keys, this implies as your user. If so, why would you `su youruser`(you said: `su myself`)?  Do you mean you can't `sudo command`?

Comment: Read `man passwd`, and consider reading `man -k passwd`.

Comment: `passwd` is certainly worth a try but you typically have to enter your old password first, so that might not work either …

Comment: Do you have physical access to the system? If so you can reset the password from a live session. If the server has a terminal you can also reset from grub rescue prompt.